# Problems with D3.js graph - single data element won't show up

Tags: d3.js

I've got a D3.js graph that works great when (a) there is more than one data element to graph and (b) if there is a mixture of positive and negative numbers, but I have problems if it breaks either of these rules.

I think the problem may be with how the y domain is calculated, or how the y scale is calculated using d3.scale.linear().

I've created a jsfiddle project to show the problem.  There are three data sets at the top of the Javascript panel - if you comment the arrays in/out you can see the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/L2wrnecm/

```
  //data = [["A",-1],["B",2]];  //this works
  data = [["A",1],["B",2]];     //this doesn't work - 0 scale is off when 
                                //both are positive
  //data = [["A",-1]];          //this does not work - with only element it 
                                //does not show up
```

Thanks for any help - fc

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need some checks on your extent:

```
var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){return d[1]});
extent[0] = extent[0] > 0 ? 0 : extent[0];
extent[1] = extent[1] < 0 ? 0 : extent[1];

yScale
  .domain(extent)                
  .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
  .nice();
```

Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2wrnecm/1/).

Comment: That works, thank you very much, it gets me where I need to go.  Mark I owe you a beer.  Here's the revised jsFiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/L2wrnecm/2/     Thanks again.